# Laravel DB:select() requires all columns in the group by

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, mariadb

I need to run a custom query and I have tried all these methods

```
$sql = "SELECT acd.*, DATE_FORMAT(acd.cdate, '%d/%m/%Y') cdate_disp,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(', ', car.type, car.session, crd.name) SEPARATOR '<br />') rd_names,
  acb.booking_status my_booking_status
FROM app_data acd
INNER JOIN crmaccounts ca ON ca.id = acd.client_crm_id
LEFT JOIN crmaccount_rdids car ON car.account_id = ca.id
LEFT JOIN crmrd_ids crd ON crd.id = car.rd_id
LEFT JOIN app_bookings acb ON acb.call_ref_id = acd.call_ref AND acb.user_id = 12391
WHERE 1=1 
AND acd.client_crm_id NOT IN (select account_id from bstaff WHERE user_id=12391)
GROUP BY acd.id
ORDER BY acd.cdate, ctiming";

DB:select($sql);
```

throws

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42000)
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'mydatabase.acd.call_ref' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: ....)

```
DB::select($sql);

DB::raw($sql);

DB::select(DB::raw($sql));

//even with pdo 
$sth = DB::getPdo()->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
$data = $sth->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

 PDOException (42000)
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'mydatabase.acd.call_ref' isn't in GROUP BY
```

It seems like the only way to get working is to list all the table columns in the `group by` which is doable but not convenient.

I am able to run the same query directly in the phpmyadmin. So I am not sure why when I run it through Laravel it asks me add all columns.

I have MariaDB installed and both Laravel and PhpMyAdmin are connecting to the same instance. Larvel version is 5.8.5.

Please take a look at full query as I asked question here too but couldn't find any answer - https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/query-runs-ok-in-phpmyadmin-but-dbselect-throws-exception

Comment: Try to disable strict mode in `config/database.php` in mysql connection section.

Comment: @dparoli - Yes!!! that let the query run! What are the down sides of disabling strict? I need to understand it's impact. Or Can I just disable it before running this query and enable after it programmatically?

Comment: you can find what is enabled in strict mode in the sourcecode, search here: `Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should try disabling the strict mode in `config/database.php`, in mysql connection section.

Comment: As you were the first one to point it out, I have accepted your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Laravel issue, but a logical limitation by MySQL. When you add columns to your results set that are not in the `GROUP BY` clause, different values could be possible for these columns in the result set.

When executing queries in strict mode (which is on by default), MySQL will not allow this because it could lead to unexpected results. If you turn off strict mode MySQL will use the first result it finds for these columns.

You can turn off strict mode in your Laravel config files in `config/database.php`. However, it is recommended to change your query instead because of the unpredictability.

A full list of checks in strict mode can be found in the MySQL documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Laravel 4.8 and also configured Auth. further more,I add two tables called as role and states and tried your pdo code - its perfectly works for me! Here, I put my code.

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM users u
            INNER JOIN roles r ON r.id = u.role_id
            LEFT JOIN states s ON s.id = u.state_id

            WHERE 1=1 

            GROUP BY u.id
            ORDER BY u.id ";

    $sth = DB::getPdo()->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute();
    $data = $sth->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    dd($data);
```

I am eager to know what is your db structure.

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.8.5 and there is config value which enables strict mode. Maybe in Laravel 4.8 the strict mode is set to off or it isn't there?

Comment: I cross check with config/database.php and found it is true by default. you can check into the file 'connection => mysql => strict'

Comment: Yes I have strict set to true.

Comment: True is a default for me so I suppose you have too